# How to save high scores and time in my game SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a game in which I want to make a top 10 results and the results are going to be made of 2 things - difficulty (easy, medium, hard) and score(integer). So far I am trying for sometime now to understand how this SQLite works in Android studio and I am still confused but after reading several tutorials here is what I managed to put together: DBHandler class

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "highscores";

private static  final String TABLE_DETAIL = "scores";

private static  final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static  final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static  final String KEY_DIFFICULTY = "difficutly";


public DBHandler(Context context){ super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_HIGHSCORES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_DETAIL + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_TIME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_DIFFICULTY + " TEXT, ";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_HIGHSCORES_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DETAIL);     // tova maha starata tablica ako s16testvuva

    onCreate(db);                                           // tova q pravi nanovo
}
// Adding new score
public void addScore(int score) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_TIME, score); // score value

    // Inserting Values
    db.insert(TABLE_DETAIL, null, values);

    db.close();

}

// Getting All Scores
public String[] getAllScores() {

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DETAIL;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list

    int i = 0;

    String[] data = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        data[i] = cursor.getString(1);

        i = i++;

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return score array
    return data;
}
}
```

This class below, I don't know why it is even required but I saw it in every tutorial so I copy it...

```
public class Contact {

//private variables
int _id;
String difficulty;
String time;

// Empty constructor
public Contact(){

}
// constructor
public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
    this._id = id;
    this.difficulty = name;
    this.time = _phone_number;
}

// constructor
public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){
    this.difficulty = name;
    this.time = _phone_number;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this.difficulty;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this.difficulty = name;
}
```

and the last class

```
public class highscores extends Activity {

private ListView scorebox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
    scorebox = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scorebox);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscores);
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addScore(9000);
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
}
}
```

I tried in the last class to put some data just to test the database but application crashes as soon as I click the button to open the database and this is where I gave up and decided to ask for help.
The error is a very long one:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.user.myapplication, PID: 24731
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.myapplication/com.example.user.myapplication.highscores}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEscores": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEscores(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, difficutly TEXT,
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEscores": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEscores(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, difficutly TEXT,
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                  at com.example.user.myapplication.DBHandler.onCreate(DBHandler.java:34)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                  at com.example.user.myapplication.DBHandler.addScore(DBHandler.java:46)
                  at com.example.user.myapplication.highscores.onCreate(highscores.java:25)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please refine your code snippets. It's difficult for us to parse through all of the code from your project. If you can try to pinpoint your issue, and only provide that code, it could be easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error in your sql.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEscores": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEscores(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, difficutly TEXT,

It should be space after `TABLE`.

Comment: Ok, thank you I fixed that error, but not it just loads a blank page instead of  `db.addScore(9000);`

Comment: If your question was answered - mark answer it as right one. If you have another questions - feel free create another question.